# 'yield from' outside of function

Tags: python, bots, discord, yield, discord.py

So I have this code for a discord bot that will keep track/add/remove points. I'm pretty new to python and all the errors so far I've either fixed by luck or with some google help, but I can't seem to figure how to fix this bit. Whenever I try to run the code, I get

> "yield from" outside of function.

How would I solve that issue?

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def func(self): passon_message (self, message)
if message.content.startswith('p!'):
        if message.content[2] in self.houses:
            split_message = message.content.split()
            if split_message[0] == f'p!{message.content[2]}':
                if split_message[1] == 'add' or split_message[1] == 'remove':
                    if split_message[2].isdigit():
                        if split_message[1] == 'add':
                            old_points = self.bot.hp.data.get('housepoints').get(self.houses.get(message.content[2])).get('points')
                            self.bot.hp.data['housepoints'][self.houses.get(message.content[2])]['points'] = old_points + int(split_message[2])
                            self.bot.hp.save()
                            yield from message.channel.send('added')
                        if split_message[1] == 'remove':
                            old_points = self.bot.hp.data.get('housepoints').get(self.houses.get(message.content[2])).get('points')
                            self.bot.hp.data['housepoints'][self.houses.get(message.content[2])]['points'] = old_points - int(split_message[2])
                            self.bot.hp.save()
                            yield from message.channel.send('removed')
```

> EDIT:

Here is an image of the code. Couldn't make it look nicer here 
Code:

[image: Code]

Comment: If the indentation in your question matches that in the code file, then the `func` function only contains the statement `passon_message (self, message)`, meaning that your `yield from` statements are indeed outside the function. Try indenting the third line (`if message.content.startswith('p!'):`) and putting the `passon_message` call on a line of its own, also indented.

Comment: It's hard to tell with your indentation but if `def func(self):` and `passon_message(self, message)` are on the same line, then the function definition is complete and the rest of the code here is not actually included.

Comment: Please, fix the indentation/formatting of your code so that it looks exactly the same as that in your editor. If it's already that way, you _really_ need to look at Python's PEP-0008 for code style guidelines you _really_ should follow.

Comment: @Newbie-To-Py I see that the code looks the same in your editor. Please look at the PEP-0008 for ways in which you can really improve the readability of your code and lower the chances of running into syntax errors or unexpected behaviors due to different indentation.

Comment: `yield from` isn't typically something you'd use as a new python programmer, are you sure you know what it does?

Comment: @RyanHaining Kinda... Everything I know about coding so far is self-taught. So basically I'm running on trial and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Your screenshot confirms [my comment's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127346/yield-from-outside-of-function#comment93149346_53127346) theory, so posting it as an answer for you to accept.)

Python identifies which code is contained in a function (or `if` statement, `for` loop, ...) by indentation. If you place a statement on the same line, like so:

```
def foo(): print("Hello.")
```

it assumes that the function only contains that statement. So in your code only the statement `passon_message (self, message)` is inside `func`. To include all of those lines, you'll need to put that statement on a new, indented line, and indent the following `if` statement:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def func(self):
    passon_message (self, message)
    if message.content.startswith('p!'):
        if message.content[2] in self.houses:
            split_message = message.content.split()
            # ...
```